# Boost condition variable equivalent with CRITICAL_SECTION

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, critical-section

I currently have a boost::mutex code section in my application that looks something like this

```
{//Lock
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(some_mutex);
   while(container.empty()) 
   { 
     condition_var.wait(lock); 
   }/*Block if empty - for spurious wakeup*/ 
 ......
 ,,,,,,
}//Unlock
```

Now some_mutex is of type boost::mutex
and condition_var is of type  boost::condition_variable

Now condition_var is triggered with `condition_var.notifyone()` method unfortunately this method takes boost::mutex to function.
I am planning on removing the boost::mutex and using windows provided CRITICAL_SECTION. However I believe the boost condition does not work with windows CRITICAL_SECTION
any suggestion on what my options might be to replace the boost::mutex  with CRITICAL_SECTION with minimum change in the above code ?

Comment: You will need to wrap the CRITICAL_SECTION code in a class that provides lock/unlock methods, and then you can use `boost::condition_variable_any`, which accepts any class which implements the Lockable concept.

Comment: Why do you plan to replace? boost::mutex is equivalent to CRITICAL_SECTION functionally.

Comment: I very much doubt that `CRITICAL_SECTION` is faster than `boost::mutex`.  Look at boost\thread\win32\basic_timed_mutex.hpp.  This is what gets inlined into your code.  In the common case of an uncontended mutex it's basically an inlined test-and-set.  CRITICAL_SECTION does a procedure call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `boost::condition_variable_any` with any mutex-like object such a `CRITICAL_SECTION`. (as DaveS comment says)

But, I strongly recommend you to do profiling speed and compare your first simple version to the following code.

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp>

// wrapper class for CriticalSection
class win32cs_mutex : boost::noncopyable {
public:
  win32cs_mutex()  { ::InitializeCriticalSection(&cs_); }
  ~win32cs_mutex() { ::DeleteCriticalSection(&cs_); }
  void lock()   { ::EnterCriticalSection(&cs_); }
  void unlock() { ::LeaveCriticalSection(&cs_): }
private:
  CRITICAL_SECTION cs_;
};

win32cs_mutex some_mutex;
boost::condition_variable_any condition_var;

// client code
{
  boost::unique_lock<win32cs_mutex> lock(some_mutex);
  while(container.empty()) 
  {
    condition_var.wait(lock); 
  }
  ...
}
```